# Footer won't stay in place on single page - chrome only

Tags: css, google-chrome, footer

I recently created my new website layout, after some work I got the footer to stick on the end of the page on firefox and chrome but when you go to the single.php (single post page on wordpress) my footer is out of place

my blog: endingunplanned.com

```
    <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>        
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="post">
    <div class="info1">
      <div class="date"><div class="date"><br />

    <div class="date-month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></div>
    <div class="date-day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></div>
</div></div>
      <div class="title">     <div align="center"><?php the_title(); ?> <br />
    </div></div>
    </div>


    <div class="post-content"><?php the_content('Continue lendo &raquo;'); ?> </div>
<div class="post-stuff"><div align="center"><div class="tag"> posted in:  <?php the_tags('', ', '); ?> - <?php comments_popup_link(__('0 Comments'), __('1 Comment'), __('% Comments'),'Commentslink', __('Comments are closed')); ?> 

</div>     
</div> 
<?php if (function_exists('paged_comments_template')) paged_comments_template(); else comments_template(); ?> 
</div> 
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?><?php else : ?><?php endif; ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

css

```
    @charset "utf-8";

body,td,th {

    font-family: verdana;

    font-size: 11px;

    color: #333333;

margin:0;

padding:0;

text-align:center; /* hack para o IE */ 

padding: 0 0 0 0;

}



#all {

    width: 1000px;

position: relative;

margin:0 auto;         

text-align:left; /* "remédio" para o hack do IE */

}



a:link {

    color: #111111;

    text-decoration: none;

}

a:visited {

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #111111;

}

a:hover {

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #FF9999;

}



a:active {

    text-decoration: none;

    color: #111111;

}



.menusize {

    background-color: #http://twitter.com/ ;

    width: 1000px;

    color: #FFFFFF;

}

    #menu ul {

    padding:0px;

    margin:0px;

    background-color:#ff9999;

    list-style:none;

    text-align: center;

    vertical-align: middle;

    line-height: 40px;

    font-family: verdana;

    font-size: 15px;

    font-variant: small-caps;

    color: #FFFFFF;

    }

    #menu ul li { display: inline; }



    #menu ul li a {

    padding: 2px 10px;

    display: inline-block;

    /* visual do link */

    background-color:#ff9999;

    color: #FFFFFF;

    text-decoration: none;

    }.post {

    clear: left;

    float: left;

    width: 690px;

}



.date {

    clear: left;

    float: left;

    background:#fff url('date.png') no-repeat scroll top left;

    width:80px;

    height:80px;

    color:#FFFFFF;

    text-align:center;

}

.date .date-month {

    height:18px;

    font-size:13px;

    font-family:verdana;

    font-weight:bold;

}

.date .date-day {

    font-family:verdana;

    font-size:18px;

}



.title {

font-family: 'Vibur', cursive;

font-size: 30px;

}

.post {

padding-bottom: 5px;

}



.tag {font: 12px/20px Arial; color:#333333; text-transform: uppercase; padding: 5px 0 0 0; height: 20px; overflow: hidden; -moz-border-radius: 15px;

border-radius: 15px;}

.tag a {color:#FFFFFF; background:#ff9999; padding: 3px 5px 3px;-moz-border-radius: 15px;

border-radius: 15px;}

.tag a:hover {color:#FFFFFF; background:#88cfd5; -moz-border-radius: 15px;

border-radius: 15px;}



.sidebar {

    clear: right;

    float: right;

    width: 300px;

}



.footer {

    background-color: #88CFD5;

    clear: both;

    float: none;

height:auto;

position:absolute;

bottom:0;

left:0;

width: 100%;

}



h1 {

    font-size: 14px;

    color: #333333;

}
```

Comment: Please turn this in jsfiddle. This is unclear...

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you could turn this into a jsfiddle or something? Your code is a little hard to wade through.